# How to cite something when you cannot remember where you've read it?

Tags: citations

Let's say you're writing a paper about a novel problem in Mathematics. While writing the paper you remember an interesting result concerning a different related problem. You can derive that result from memory, but you cannot remember where exactly you've read it - it could've been a paper, a pre-print on Arxiv.org, a post on Math.SE, a book from the library, a lecture that you've attended, etc. No matter how hard you try you cannot find the exact source.

What is one supposed to do in this situation?

Comment: Step 1: search harder. Step 2: ask colleagues. Step 3: claim as a folklore result.

Comment: "it can be shown that...". And don't claim it among your contributions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're already here, an obvious step would be to post a question on a relevant Stack Exchange site. (Other websites are available.) Such questions are routinely asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net), for example.

Similarly, asking colleagues can also work. They don't necessarily need to be people you know personally either. There's often someone in a field with a reputation for a "near-encyclopedic knowledge of the literature" you could send an email to.

However, if nothing works, honesty is the best approach. Just present it as a known result of unknown origin, or something to that effect. [Here's](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.0122.pdf) an example where that kind of formulation is used for a problem, not a result, but the same idea applies.

Comment: That's a good way of searching for a reference. But what if nothing helps and you just don't can't find it?

Comment: There's also often someone who seems to know everyone in the field and what they're working on, so that when you ask that person a question, you'll get the response of "I don't know, but try asking X."  If X doesn't know either, he or she might refer you to someone else, and, several e-mails later, you can get an answer.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Yes, tenacity is certainly required sometimes.